# can we compare widgets in wordpress as blocks in drupal

Tags: wordpress, drupal

I'm a bit new to Wordpress. I found the terms in wordpress very different from Drupal.
Can we compare widgets in Wordpress as blocks in Drupal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes definitely you can compare widgets in wordpress as block in drupal

In wordpress,
We can define area for widgets to render.

In drupal,
We define regions for blocks to render.